# How to remove "&per_page=" from URL in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am stuck on this problem. I'm facing the issue at my URL. I am getting `&per_page=` in my URL.

I am using pagination in CI in which I had used following code but not able to remove it.

> MY URL:  http://localhost/abroad_education/entrance/index/0&per_page=3
>
> Expected URL:  http://localhost/abroad_education/entrance/index/0/3

**Controller**

```
class Entrance extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{ 
    parent::__construct();  
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');

    $this->load->model('Pagination_model',"pgn");
}

public function index()
{   


    if($this->input->post('title') !="")
    {
        $title = trim($this->input->post('title'));
    }
    else{
        $title = str_replace("%20",' ',($this->uri->segment(3))?$this->uri->segment(3):0);
    } 

    $data['search_title']=$title;       
    print_r($title); 
    $allrecord = $this->pgn->allrecord($title);
    $baseurl =  base_url().$this->router->class.'/'.$this->router->method."/".$title;

    $paging=array();
    $paging['base_url'] =$baseurl;
    $paging['total_rows'] = $allrecord;
    $paging['per_page'] = 3;
    $paging['uri_segment']= 4;
    $paging['num_links'] = 8;
    $paging['first_link'] = 'First';
    $paging['first_tag_open'] = '<li>>';
    $paging['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $paging['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $paging['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $paging['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
    $paging['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $paging['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $paging['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $paging['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $paging['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $paging['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $paging['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $paging['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $paging['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0);">';
    $paging['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($paging); 

    $data['limit'] = $paging['per_page'];
    $data['number_page'] = $paging['per_page']; 
    $data['offset'] = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4):'0/';   
    $data['nav'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['datas'] = $this->pgn->data_list($data['limit'],$data['offset'],$title);
    $data['include'] = 'frontend/entrance/entrance';
    $this->load->view('frontend/container', $data);
}

}
```

**Model**

```
class Pagination_model extends CI_Model{
function __construct(){
parent::__construct();  
    $this->load->library(array('session','pagination'));
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->database();    
}


public function allrecord($title){
    if(!empty($title)){
        $this->db->like('ee_name',$title);
    }
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('vm_entrance_exams');
    $rs = $this->db->get();
    return $rs->num_rows();
}

public function data_list($limit,$offset,$title){
    if(!empty($title)){
        $this->db->like('ee_name',$title);
    }
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('vm_entrance_exams');
    $this->db->order_by('ee_id','ee_desc');
    $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
    $rs = $this->db->get();
    return $rs->result_array();
}
}
```

Comment: I've used pagination a lot, but never come this issues as  by default. It may be due to this `$baseurl =  base_url().$this->router->class.'/'.$this->router->method."/".$title;`

Comment: I'll do pagination base url like this  `$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'product/productBrand/'.$id;`. Cz i knw the actual URL of it instead of magic methods like `$this->router->method`

Comment: @AbdullaNilam . i tried even that same "&per_page=" repeating .. instead of this i only need ' / '.. and only then my code works.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam .. Thank u sir .. I got the solution ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that you have 'enable_query_strings' set to false in /application/config.php

```
 $config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

From the [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html).

> If you have $config['enable_query_strings'] set to TRUE your links
>   will automatically be re-written using Query Strings. This option can
>   also be explicitly set.